# How do you analyze this simple circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, differential-amplifier, current-sensing

I want to plot Vout vs time graph (which software do you suggest) and also want to find out max and min output voltage (Vout) of the circuit. How can I find the max and min manually?
Can I find them using KVL and KCL? Can you show a sample on to analyze it?
[image: The Circuit]

Comment: For the software, there are many  simulation software out there, but I personally use LTSpice, it's free and it's intuitive to work with. in terms of analysis, reinforce the fact that ideal op amps have infinite impedance at their input (so no current draw IDEALLY) and you can also see that your V- = R3/(R5+R3) *Vout and the fact that V-=V+ (ideally), the rest is pretty easy.

Comment: To understand the circuit, first you have to figure out the function of R1, then the 4-resistor op-amp circuit. Note that the op-amp is single-supplied and also that R4 is connected to +5V (instead to ground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLfLZ6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_2\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_4-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_2=\text{V}_3:=\text{V}_x\tag3$$

Now, we can solve for the output voltage:

$$\text{V}_4=\frac{\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_5\right)\left(\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{I}_\text{k}\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V2 = Vx;
V3 = Vx;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == Ik + I2, I1 == V1/R1, I2 == (V2 - V1)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, 
   I2 == (Vi - V2)/R4, I3 == (V4 - V3)/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, Vx, V1, V4}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (Ik (R2 + R4) + Vi)/(R1 + R2 + R4), 
  I2 -> (-Ik R1 + Vi)/(R1 + R2 + R4), 
  I3 -> (Ik R1 R4 + (R1 + R2) Vi)/(R3 (R1 + R2 + R4)), 
  Vx -> (Ik R1 R4 + (R1 + R2) Vi)/(R1 + R2 + R4), 
  V1 -> (R1 (Ik (R2 + R4) + Vi))/(R1 + R2 + R4), 
  V4 -> ((R3 + R5) (Ik R1 R4 + (R1 + R2) Vi))/(R3 (R1 + R2 + R4))}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

Using your values and the fact that \$\text{I}_\text{k}\$ is time dependent, we can see that:

$$\text{V}_4\left(t\right)=\frac{295\left(1000001+4000\cdot\text{I}_\text{k}\left(t\right)\right)}{189000009}\tag5$$

We can model your current source as follows:

$$\text{I}_\text{k}\left(t\right)=100\left(\theta\left(t-3\right)+\theta\left(t-1\right)-2\theta\left(t-2\right)\right)\tag6$$

Plotting that, gives:

[image]

Where \$\theta\left(\cdot\right)\$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Subsituting that in, we get the output voltage:

$$\text{V}_4\left(t\right)=\frac{295\left(1000001+400000\left(\theta\left(t-3\right)+\theta\left(t-1\right)-2\theta\left(t-2\right)\right)\right)}{189000009}\tag7$$

Plotting that, gives:

[image]

So, we can see that we have three different voltage levels:

1. $$\text{V}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\text{V}_4\left(6\right)=\frac{295000295}{189000009}\approx1.56085\space\text{V}\tag8$$
2. $$\text{V}_4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{137666765}{63000003}\approx2.18519\space\text{V}\tag9$$
3. $$\text{V}_4\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)=\frac{177000295}{189000009}\approx0.936509\space\text{V}\tag{10}$$

Putting that that into the plot from above:

[image]